# Importing Facebook API data as JSON Object into Google Sheets results in mismatched Dates value

Tags: arrays, json, excel, facebook-graph-api, google-sheets

**Goal:** Import client data from Facebook Graph API into a Google Sheet to create a dynamic Facebook Ads Dashboard

**What I've tried:**

1. Downloaded Google Sheet script that includes an ImportJSON function which is meant to import a JSON feed and flatten it into a two-dimensional array [ImportJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON)
2. Used ImportJSON with a Graph API query created by Faceook's Graph API Explorer. That looks something like this:

`/insights?date_preset=lifetime&time_increment=1&fields=account_currency,spend,frequency,reach,impressions,actions,cpm&use_account_attribution_setting=true&limit=5000`

**Result:** Returns 2d-array in Google Sheet filled with the data we want. So far so good.

**Problem:** The dates are all off by one day (one day behind) for the values associated with query field "actions"

Query field "actions" returns an object with key "actions" and a value which is an array of objects whose keys and values correspond to different kinds of actions users are taking in response to our ads.

All of these are behind by one day.

**My Investigation:**
[Google Sheets Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Eh2.png)

```
  "data": [
    {
      "account_currency": "USD",
      "spend": "14.76",
      "frequency": "1.263227",
      "reach": "4593",
      "impressions": "5802",
      "cpm": "2.54395",
      "actions": [
        {
          "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "onsite_conversion.view_content",
          "value": "4"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_conversation_started_7d",
          "value": "19"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "comment",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "link_click",
          "value": "45"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_custom",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post",
          "value": "5"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_reaction",
          "value": "25"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "omni_view_content",
          "value": "5"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "page_engagement",
          "value": "76"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_engagement",
          "value": "76"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "view_content",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ],
      "date_start": "2020-11-04",
      "date_stop": "2020-11-04"
    },
    {
      "account_currency": "USD",
      "spend": "21.61",
      "frequency": "1.249471",
      "reach": "6145",
      "impressions": "7678",
      "cpm": "2.814535",
      "actions": [
        {
          "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_conversation_started_7d",
          "value": "13"
```

When I look at the sample of my JSON attached and compare it to the Google Sheets output, it looks to me like the "actions" keys and values are inheriting the "date_start" and "date_stop" values of the **prior object** and that is what is throwing my data off.

**Question:** Have I diagnosed this correctly? If so, how can ensure the "actions" are associated with the correct date?

Thanks for reading this. I hope my problem is described clearly.

I'm teaching myself this stuff so my vocabulary is probably a little shoddy!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the library you're using is applying its default transformation function to the data https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs#L428 which in this case, won't transform the data in the way you want.

You would have to write your own transformation function to handle the specific shape of the expected data.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense. Appreciate you taking the time to help.